# How to print text during assembly in gnu assembler?

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu

For example, I want to know how many bytes are alloted for certain instructions without running the output file.

```
start:
movl $0,%eax;movl $0,%ebx
end:

.print end-start
```

Comment: I don’t think there is any such directive. There isn’t one listed at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas/html_chapter/as_7.html.

Comment: When code-golfing and comparing different versions of a function, I usually use `.byte . - start` and look at disassembly (with `objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o`.  If you like AT&T syntax, omit the `-Mintel`.